# php mysqli insert and update queries

Tags: php, forms, jquery, mysqli

i am creating a feedback form that allow users to  write their feedback and using php and mysqli i stored these feedback in the database based on the username of the user 
i did insert data successfully but without username of the user  so the problem is :
when i wrote an update query i become unable to insert any data  can anyone help me ??

## feedback_form.php

```
<?php

session_start();
 $login = ($_SESSION['login']);
   $userid = ($_SESSION['user_id']);
   $login_user = ($_SESSION['username']);
   $fname = ($_SESSION['first_name']);
   $lname = ($_SESSION['last_name']);
   $sessionaddres =($_SESSION['address']);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>feedback page</title>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="style/stylesheet.css"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
    $(function(){
       $('#submit').click(function(){
         $('#container').append('<img src = "images/loading.gif" alt="Currently loading" id = "loading" />');
             var comments = $('#comments').val();
             $.ajax({
                url: 'feedback_process.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {"comments": comments},
                success: function(result){
                     $('#response').remove();
                     $('#container').append('<p id = "response">' + result + '</p>');
                     $('#loading').fadeOut(500, function(){
                         $(this).remove();
                     });
                }
             });         
            return false;
       });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
<?php require_once('header.php'); ?>
<body>
<form action = "feedback_form.php" method = "post">
  <div id = "container">
            <h2><?php echo $login_user ?></h2>

          <label for = "comments">Comments</label>
          <textarea rows = "5"cols = "35" name = "comments" id = "comments"></textarea>
          <br />
  </div>
   </form>
       <input type = "submit" name = "submit" id = "submit" value = "send feedBack" />
</body>
</html>
```

## feedback_process.php

```
<?php

session_start();

 $login = ($_SESSION['login']);
   $userid = ($_SESSION['user_id']);
   $login_user = ($_SESSION['username']);
   $fname = ($_SESSION['first_name']);
   $lname = ($_SESSION['last_name']);
   $sessionaddres =($_SESSION['address']);


$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'lam_el_chamel_db');

  echo"<pre>";
  print_r($_POST);
  echo"</pre>";

  if(isset($_POST['comments'])){

  $comments = $_POST['comments'];



  $query = "INSERT into feedback (feedback_text user_name,) VALUES(?,?)";

  $stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
  if($stmt->prepare($query))
  {

     $stmt->bind_param('ss', $comments, $login_user);
     //$stmt->execute();

  }
  $query2 = "UPDATE feedback SET (feedback = ?, user_name = ?) WHERE user_name = '$login_user' ";
  $stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
  if($stmt->prepare($query))
  {
     $stmt->bind_param('ss', $comments, $login_user);
     $stmt->execute();

  }



  if($stmt){

  echo "thank you .we will be in touch soon <br />";

  }
  else{
   echo "there was an error. try again later.";
   }  

}

else
   echo"it is a big error";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $query2 = "UPDATE feedback SET (feedback = ?, user_name = ?) WHERE user_name = '$login_user' ";
  $stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
  if($stmt->prepare($query2))
```

Comment: execute statement for insert is comment in your code `//$stmt->execute();`

Comment: there is another one under **$stmt->bind_param('ss', $comments, $login_user);**

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
  $query2 = "UPDATE feedback SET (feedback = ?, user_name = ?) WHERE user_name = '$login_user' ";
  $stmt = $conn->query($query2);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one errors/mistakes.

See the following code segments:

### First

```
$query = "INSERT into feedback (feedback_text user_name,) VALUES(?,?)";
```

You don't have a `,`(comma) separating the fields. Use:

```
$query = "INSERT into feedback (feedback_text, user_name) VALUES(?, ?)";
```

### Next

```
 //$stmt->execute();
```

You are not executing this statement. Use

```
 $stmt->execute();
```

### Another

```
$query2 = "UPDATE feedback SET (feedback = ?, user_name = ?) WHERE user_name = '$login_user' ";
```

The field name is different here and above in `INSERT` query. Maybe try

```
$query2 = "UPDATE feedback SET feedback_text = ?, user_name = ? WHERE user_name = ? ";
$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
if($stmt->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $comments, $login_user, $login_user);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```