# php mysqli with insert and update queries

Tags: php, mysql, forms, jquery

i am creating a feedback form where users can write their feedback and store it in the database using php mysqli  without refreshing the whole  page  . i got the success message but without any entered data  can anyone help me ? i asked yesterday the same question [php mysqli insert and update queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593423/php-mysqli-insert-and-update-queries/15595900?noredirect=1#15595900)

## feedback_form.php

```
<?php

session_start();

 $login = ($_SESSION['login']);
   $userid = ($_SESSION['user_id']);
   $login_user = ($_SESSION['username']);
   $fname = ($_SESSION['first_name']);
   $lname = ($_SESSION['last_name']);
   $sessionaddres =($_SESSION['address']);


?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>feedback page</title>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="style/stylesheet.css"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <script type = "text/javascript">

    $(function(){

       $('#submit').click(function(){
         $('#container').append('<img src = "images/loading.gif" alt="Currently loading" id = "loading" />');


             var comments = $('#comments').val();


             $.ajax({

                url: 'feedback_process.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {"comments": comments},

                success: function(result){
                     $('#response').remove();
                     $('#container').append('<p id = "response">' + result + '</p>');
                     $('#loading').fadeOut(500, function(){
                         $(this).remove();
                     });

                }

             });         

            return false;

       });


    });

    </script>




    </head>
<?php require_once('header.php'); ?>

<body>
<form action = "feedback_form.php" method = "post">
  <div id = "container">
            <h2><?php echo $login_user ?></h2>



          <label for = "comments">Comments</label>
          <textarea rows = "5"cols = "35" name = "comments" id = "comments"></textarea>
          <br />
  </div>
   </form>
       <input type = "submit" name = "submit" id = "submit" value = "send feedBack" />




</body>
</html>
```

## feedback_process.php

```
<?php

session_start();

 $login = ($_SESSION['login']);
   $userid = ($_SESSION['user_id']);
   $login_user = ($_SESSION['username']);
   $fname = ($_SESSION['first_name']);
   $lname = ($_SESSION['last_name']);
   $sessionaddres =($_SESSION['address']);


$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'lam_el_chamel_db');

  echo"<pre>";
  print_r($_POST);
  echo"</pre>";

  if(isset($_POST['comments'])){

  $comments = $_POST['comments'];



  $query = "INSERT into feedback (feedback_text, user_name,) VALUES(?,?)";

  $stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
  if($stmt->prepare($query))
  {

     $stmt->bind_param('ss', $comments, $login_user);
     $stmt->execute();

  }
  $query2 = "UPDATE feedback SET feedback_text = ?, user_name = ? WHERE user_name = ? ";
  $stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
  if($stmt->prepare($query2))
  {
     $stmt->bind_param('sss', $comments, $login_user, $login_user);
     $stmt->execute();

  }



  if($stmt){

  echo "thank you .we will be in touch soon <br />";

  }
  else{
   echo "there was an error. try again later.";
   }  

}

else
   echo"it is a big error";
?>
```

Comment: If you have already asked this question why are you posting it again? If the answers given don't help then explain why they don't and the person who gave the response will try to help

Comment: i asked again because no one  had answer me after the last reply that i get it and still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

First: Don't ask questions two times. You won't get better or quicker answers just because you answer them twice...

The success message just tells you that you've *accessed* a file with success (and not anything else). Based on this, I would try to run feedback_process.php alone (without involvement of feedback_form.php) with a "dummy" comment and "dummy" login_user. I also added output of "failed" when insert query did not work... (Your code actually just implemented success or not for the the update feedback-query (last one))

I hope the code down below will help you...

```
<?php
session_start();

$login = ($_SESSION['login']); 
$userid = ($_SESSION['user_id']);
$login_user = ($_SESSION['username']);
$fname = ($_SESSION['first_name']);
$lname = ($_SESSION['last_name']);
$sessionaddres =($_SESSION['address']);


$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'lam_el_chamel_db');

echo"<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo"</pre>";


//Some dummys for debugging
$comments = 'This is the comments'; 
$login_user = 'FOO';


$query = "INSERT into feedback (feedback_text, user_name) VALUES(?,?)";

$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
if($stmt->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $comments, $login_user);
    $stmt->execute();
}
else {
    echo 'FAILED!';
}

$query2 = "UPDATE feedback SET feedback_text = ?, user_name = ? WHERE user_name = ? ";
$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
if($stmt->prepare($query2)) {
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $comments, $login_user, $login_user);
    $stmt->execute();
}
else {
    echo 'FAILED!';
}

if($stmt){
    echo "thank you .we will be in touch soon <br />";
}
else {
    echo "there was an error. try again later.";
}  

?>
```